# Java regex doesn't work

Tags: java, regex

Having a slight regex problem. I wrote to following code to check if a word is contained within a String.

```
boolean matches = Pattern.matches("\\b" + Pattern.quote(item.name) + "\\b", nap.code);
```

item.name will be something like "half"
nap.code will be something like "int halfOfFour() { return half(4); }"

Yet, my pattern match returns false... What am I doing wrong here?

Also... Is there anyway to make this return false if the word is contained within a string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the pattern match will match the *whole* string not just a part of it. so prefix with .* and postfix with .* or something.

use pattern and matches separately and then use "find()" in matcher to find submatches

Comment: of course i assume that you dont want to use string contains or indexOf/lastIndexOf

Comment: `System.out.println ("int halfOfFour() { return half(4); }".matches(".*\\bhalf\\b.*"));` --> true

Comment: "testfunc passing() {
    int halfOfFour = half(4);
    assert(halfOfFour == 2, "The laws of physics is on break");
}".matches(".*\\b" + Pattern.quote("half") + "\\b.*");

Still results in false...

Comment: then you need to use the pattern/matcher separately to find submatches.

Comment: It worked... But I also have an additional question, updated my question to reflect that!

Comment: try ".*\\W+"+pattern.quote(item.name)+"\\W+.*" or something.

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't the `Java.lang.String.contains()` method do what you want?

```
boolean contains = nap.code.contains(item.name);
```

EDIT : To return true only if the word is present, using the \W pattern (non-word character) should help you :

```
\W*(YOUR_WORD)\W*
```

Comment: No, he wants to check if a full **word** is in the string. `Canon` contains `non`, but it is not a word. `CaNon` contains the word non.

Comment: In his example (half/halfOfHour) he says it should return true despite 'half' not being a full word. So I think you misread that.

Comment: Yes, but I think he is really looking for a way to check words. The capital characters mark the beginning of a word.

Comment: Actually, i want it to return true because the string includes "half(4)"... "halfOfFour" should still return false.

Comment: Like this? boolean matches = nap.code.matches("\\W*" + Pattern.quote(item.name) + "\\W*");
Cause that still does not work...